GNU Prolog installation failed on Ubuntu
Seems like I'm unable to install properly GNU Prolog on my Ubuntu machine. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on an Asus VivoBook.
I followed the guide provided in the github https://github.com/didoudiaz/gprolog/blob/master/INSTALL, but after i run the command Make install I got an error
Could someone help me with the installation?
Thank you very much
After running:
cd src      
./configure 
make            
make install

The command  make install trigger the error:
sudo make install

./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0 /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/bin \
/usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/include /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/lib
for i in README COPYING VERSION NEWS ChangeLog gprolog.ico; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0; done
for i in gplc hexgplc gprolog pl2wam wam2ma ma2asm fd2c; do /usr/bin/install -c */$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/bin; done
for i in top_level_main.o top_level.o all_pl_bips.o debugger.o all_fd_bips.o; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 */$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/lib; done
for i in libengine_pl.a libbips_pl.a liblinedit.a libengine_fd.a libbips_fd.a; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 */$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/lib; done
for i in gprolog.h fd_to_c.h; do Tools/cpp_headers $i ./$i EnginePl EngineFD BipsPl BipsFD; /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/include; rm -f $i; done
(cd /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/lib; for i in *.a; do ranlib $i; done)
if test /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc != none; then \
   ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc; \
   (F=`cd ../doc; echo ???*.dvi ???*.ps ???*.pdf ???*.chm ???*.eps ???*.html ???*.png`; \
   for i in $F; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../doc/$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc; done); \
fi
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/???*.dvi': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/???*.ps': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/???*.chm': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/???*.html': No such file or directory
if test /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc/html_node != none; then \
   ./mkinstalldirs /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc/html_node; \
   (F=`cd ../doc/html_node; echo ???*.html ???*.css ???*.svg`; \
   for i in $F; do /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ../doc/html_node/$i /usr/local/gprolog-1.6.0/doc/html_node; done); \
fi
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/html_node/???*.html': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/html_node/???*.css': No such file or directory
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat '../doc/html_node/???*.svg': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:123: install-html] Error 1


The GNU Prolog INSTALL file lists configure options to skip installing the documentation, notably --without-html-dir. That should allow bypassing that error.
